# How to get SQL from column/query schema in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Given this QueryDef:

```
"SELECT Column1, Column2, "Prefix" + SomeColumn AS Column3 FROM SomeTable"
```

Is there a way using either VBA or SQL to extract ""Prefix" + SomeColumn" as the definition of the SomeColumn field in the SomeTable table?

Essentially I need to run a report on a list of queries of all the columns that have custom SQL in the definition.  I already have a list of the queries/columns, I'm just struggling to pull out the actual code.

Comment: How do you define a custom column? One with `As`? BTW the concatenator should be & not +, + is dangerous.

Comment: Yes basically anything that has an "As", or really any column in general.  And yes I realize that I typed that out very quickly and wasn't thinking much about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could play around with:

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef

For Each qdf In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
    For i = 0 To qdf.Fields.Count - 1
        If qdf.Fields(i).Name <> qdf.Fields(i).SourceField Then
            Debug.Print qdf.Fields(i).Name
            Debug.Print qdf.Fields(i).SourceField
            Debug.Print qdf.SQL
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Ya this is basically as far as I got on my own.  If I could come up with a good way to parse out the SQL I would be golden but so far I'm drawing mostly blanks.  Thank you though.

Comment: @Ryan What do you mean by parse out the sql? The above prints out the field names if they are not the same as in the souce table, which is what you seemed to be asking for. What else do you want to print out about the sql?

Comment: qdf.SQL returns all the SQL for the Query.  Fields(i).Name returns only the "As" portion of the column.  In the case of my above example the SourceField returns an empty string.  I am looking for a way to pull out ""Prefix" + SomeColumn" given the SQL example in the original question.

Comment: @Ryan I also include `qdf.Fields(i).Name` which is the name of the field where the field is different to the source table field, qdf.sql is the last item printed, purely for informational purposes and only where the name is different to the sourcefield.

Comment: I understand.  Neither the Name nor the SourceField return the information I am looking for.

Comment: @Ryan SQL can be very varied including sub queries as well as the numerous formats for action queries. Getting something that suits every case would take considerable time. A split on comma of the fields part of a simple select query will get quite close, but various functions also use a comma (dateadd, dlookup etc) so it will not be perfect. What is the end result you wish to achieve? Perhaps there is a lateral solution?

Comment: Ya, I was looking at splitting on commas...but a lot of the stuff I'm pulling out will be IIfs(which have commas in them).  What I am asking is maybe not possible..it is clearly not a built in functionality.  I am going to look into some regex stuff for this specific solution though.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RyanO'Neill you're much better off either doing a manual process or [purchasing a SQL Parser](http://www.sqlparser.com/access-sql-parser.php) than writing your own.